# Load html-content with jQuery AJAX request from loaded html through previous AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

In order to create a sort of Wiki-like structure, I would like to load external HTML-code into my base-page, using jQuery and AJAX. I succeeded in the first part, for loading html-content in specified divs. However, some of the loaded html-content contains another link. When I click this link (that has the same structure as the links in the original document), nothing happens. I suspect it has to do with the event listener, but I don't know how to solve it. Here is the code:

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleIndex.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {

            $('#siteContent').find('a').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                $($(this).attr('loadLocation')).load($(this).attr('loadFile'));
            });
        });     
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="siteContent">
        <h1>AJAXload test...</h1>
        <p class="para">This is a testfile, to see if I'm able to load an external HTML file in my current HTML-page 
        in a flexible way. Click 
        <a class="link" loadFile="newHTML.html" loadLocation="#loadedAjax">here</a>
        , but 
        <a class="link" loadFile="newHTML2.html" loadLocation="#loadedAjax2">I want some new content</a> 
        to change the contents of the paragrapgh below.</p>
        <div class="para"><p id="loadedAjax" class="loadedAjax">I do have some text now...but let's replace it!</p></div>

        <div class="para"><p id="loadedAjax2" class="loadedAjax">I don't ;)</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The code of the loaded html has the same structure as the a-tags in the original file.

Looking forward to your replies. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delegation rather than **binding to elements that exists during binding**

```
$('#siteContent').on('click', 'a.link', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $($(this).attr('loadLocation')).load($(this).attr('loadFile'));
});
```

> $('#siteContent').on('click', 'a.link', function(e) {..})

The above means: capture every "click" event that has occurred on '#siteContent'
anchors, and have a class called "link" on them.

This means that dynamically injected html, will always have the desired functionality.

You can read more about event delegation here:

http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

In addition, You should place the entire javascript tag just before the closing body tag (  ) as it is considered better practice.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks and I will study event-delegation to learn exactly why it worked!